# Finite subsets of Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

quick question. There is a question in the book saying "Every finite subset of a Hausdorff space is closed." The proof uses the fact that for each point in $X\setminus\{p\}$ there is a neighborhood contained in $X\setminus\{p\}$ the Hausdorff condition and hence $X\setminus\{p\}$ is open so $\{p\}$ is closed the set is the finite union finite sets.

The very next problem states: "The only Hausdorff topology on a finite set is the discrete topology." Well, in the discrete topology every $\{p\}$ is an *open* set, not closed as the proof above states. What is going on here?

Comment: Open sets can be closed.

Comment: Take an arbitrary subset. The complement is finite and thus closed, so...?

Comment: It's also the complement of an open set, hence closed. In the discrete topology, _all_ subsets are both, open and closed.

Comment: got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are true, and the issue here is that openness/closedness aren't mutually exclusive properties for a subset (as long as the space isn't connected, that is).

Answer (score 1):

While others have addressed the issue of sets being both open and closed, it seems that there might be another point of misunderstanding for the OP, which is 
that being a closed or open set is relative to the ambient topological space.

If you have a Hausdorff space $X$ and $F$ is a finite subset of $X$, then the argument you give shows that $F$ is closed *in $X$*. Now, $F$ itself carries the subspace (or induced) topology from $X$, with which it is a topological space in its own right. As with any topological space, $F$ is open *in itself*. That does not mean that it is open in $X$. These are different concepts. Since the Hausdorff condition passes to subspaces, $F$ is Hausdorff and finite, and this does indeed imply that it is discrete, so each of its subsets is open *in itself*. There is no reason that this has to imply that each subset of $F$ is open in $X$.